# Zxing core:3.5.2 decode error of encoded barcode -> NotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, zxing

I'm try decode a barcode **encoded by myself**, but i cant.
Encoded barcode reading another barcode scanner app.
I try bitmatrix and bitmap to convert BinaryBitmap but always returning null result

Yes, sometimes can return null if not decode but **how can i strong my encode code for pure decode?**

Error is
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:558) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)  Caused by: com.google.zxing.NotFoundException`

Encoder

```
class BarcodeWriter: Writer {

    override fun encode(
        contents: String?,
        format: BarcodeFormat?,
        width: Int,
        height: Int
    ): BitMatrix {
        return MultiFormatWriter().encode(contents, format, width, height)

    }

    override fun encode(
        contents: String?,
        format: BarcodeFormat?,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        hints: MutableMap<EncodeHintType, *>?
    ): BitMatrix {
        return MultiFormatWriter().encode(contents, format, width, height, hints)
    }

}
```

Decoder

```
class BarcodeReader : Reader {
    override fun decode(image: BinaryBitmap?): Result {
        return MultiFormatReader().decode(image)
    }

    override fun decode(image: BinaryBitmap?, hints: MutableMap<DecodeHintType, *>?): Result {
        return MultiFormatReader().decode(image, hints)
    }

    override fun reset() {
        //
    }
}
```

Conveters

```
fun bitMatrixToBmp(bitMatrix: BitMatrix, xColor: Int?, yColor: Int?): Bitmap {
    val height: Int = bitMatrix.height
    val width: Int = bitMatrix.width
    val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    for (x in 0 until width) {
        for (y in 0 until height) {
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, if (bitMatrix.get(x, y)) xColor?:Color.BLACK else yColor?:Color.WHITE)
        }
    }
    return bmp
}

fun bmpToBinaryBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap) : BinaryBitmap {
    val intArray = IntArray(bitmap.width * bitmap.height)
    val source = RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, intArray)
    return BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
}

fun bitMatrixToBinary(bitMatrix: BitMatrix): BinaryBitmap {
    val intArray = IntArray(bitMatrix.width * bitMatrix.height)
    val source = RGBLuminanceSource(bitMatrix.width, bitMatrix.height, intArray)
    return BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))

}
```

Barcode encode code;

```
    val hints = hashMapOf(
        EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET to "utf-8"
    )

BarcodeWriter().encode(
                    contents = "URL:${urlFormModel.url}",
                    format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                    width = 100,
                    height = 100,
                    hints = hints
                )
```

Barcode decode code;

```
           val decodeHints = hashMapOf(
                DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET to "utf-8",
                //DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE to true,
                //DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER to true
            )

            val result = BarcodeReader().decode(testBarcode.bitMatrix!!.toBinaryMap(), decodeHints)
```